# How to manage deb based packages/dependencies

Tags: apt, software-installation, elementary-os, aptitude, deb

Today I installed Elementary OS Loki into a VM.

I was surprised, that the system is so fast and pretty.

But to the point:

How to install `.deb` packages and resolve any dependencies on Elementary OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are more ways to achieve the goal, I list two [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) options, where `apt` is, subjectively, the best and recommended:

**1st choice:** **`apt`** (and `apt-get`)

```
sudo apt install ./long-package-name.deb
```

Note, that I specifically mean `apt`, not `apt-get`, because it does not auto-complete the file names, otherwise you may of course do this, if you insist on using `apt-get`, e.g. in scripts:

```
PACKAGE=$(echo long-package-name.deb)

sudo apt-get install ./$PACKAGE
```

**2nd choice:** **`gdebi`**

```
sudo gdebi long-package-name.deb
```

As I don't use `gdebi`, I can't recommend it, nor say something against it, apart from what I just tried, I will share this with you:

1. I installed a `.deb` package with `apt`
2. I ran `sudo apt update`
3. I ran `sudo apt install ./long-package-name.deb` with the expected result:

   > PACKAGE is already the newest version (VERSION).
4. I ran `sudo gdebi long-package-name.deb` with undesirable result:

   > Do you want to install the software package?

Maybe it's just me, that I don't know how to properly use `gdebi`.

Answer (score 2):

I actually prefer to use `aptitude` package manager to install/solve package  dependencies. You install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

The commands are quite similar to `apt`/ `apt-get`.

`aptitude`seems to be smarter than the other tools dealing with dependencies. It also show menus with alternatives to deal with deleting/installing procedures, and show alternatives (if and when they exist) when you refuse the first choice.

```
$sudo aptitude purge libasound2
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  libasound2{p} libasound2-data{u} 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-8-jre : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not going to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Remove the following packages:              
1)     openjdk-8-jre [8u111-b14-3 (now, testing)]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:    
1)     libasound2 [1.1.2-1 (now, testing)]                
2)     libasound2-data [1.1.2-1 (now, testing)]           

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

From the debian Aptitude [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude):

> Aptitude has a number of useful features, including:
>
> - a mutt-like syntax for matching packages in a flexible manner mark
> - packages as "automatically installed" or "manually installed" so that    packages can be auto-removed when no longer required
> - colorful preview    of actions about to be taken
> - dselect-like persistence of user actions
> - the ability to retrieve and display the Debian changelog of most    packages
> - AptCLI-like (= apt-get + apt-cache) command line mode    ("aptitude install foo")
> - Score-based and (usually) smarter dependency    resolver than apt-get

Albeit it has been classified as many years as obsolete, and it can be argued other tools provide a similar functionality, I also recommend `debfoster` to clean up the cruft of a system. `debfoster` is particularly interesting, for instance in helping trimming down a base VM to use as base install/template.

You install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install debfoster
```

I often also use it in pre-production VMs to save the actual state of packages before doing tests, and then using it´s saved state to revert to delete all the added packages as they were before I ran it.

From [HOWTO: using debfoster in practice](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24403)

> debfoster - weed unnecessary Debian packages
>
> debfoster maintains a list of installed packages that were explicitly
>   requested rather than installed as a dependency. Arguments are
>   entirely optional, debfoster can be invoked per se after each run of
>   dpkg and/or apt-get.
>
> Alternatively you can use debfoster to install and remove packages by
>   specifying the packages on the command line. Packages suffixed with a
>   - are removed while packages without a suffix are installed.
>
> If a new package is encountered or if debfoster notices that a package
>   that used to be a dependency is now an orphan, it will ask you what to
>   do with it. If you decide to keep it, debfoster will just take note
>   and continue. If you decide that this package is not interesting
>   enough it will be removed as soon as debfoster is done asking
>   questions. If your choises cause other packages to become orphaned
>   more questions will ensue.

```
$sudo debfoster

smem is keeping the following 27 packages installed:
  blt fonts-lyx libglade2-0 libjs-jquery libjs-jquery-ui liblapack3 libtk8.6 libwebp6
  libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux2 libxss1 python-cairo python-cycler python-dateutil
  python-glade2 python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-imaging python-matplotlib
  python-matplotlib-data python-numpy python-pil python-pyparsing python-tk python-tz
  tk8.6-blt2.5 ttf-bitstream-vera
Keep smem? [Ynpsiuqx?], [H]elp: Y

imvirt is keeping the following 9 packages installed:
  imvirt-helper libemail-date-format-perl libfile-slurp-perl libfile-which-perl
  libimvirt-perl libmime-lite-perl libmime-types-perl libmodule-find-perl pciutils
Keep imvirt? [Ynpsiuqx?], [H]elp: Y

linux-image-4.8.0-1-amd64-unsigned is keeping the following 9 packages installed:
  busybox firmware-linux-free initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core irqbalance
  klibc-utils libklibc libnuma1 linux-base
Keep linux-image-4.8.0-1-amd64-unsigned? [Ynpsiuqx?], [H]elp: Y

faketime is keeping the following 1 packages installed:
  libfaketime
Keep faketime? [Ynpsiuqx?], [H]elp: N

haveged is keeping the following 1 packages installed:
  libhavege1
Keep haveged? [Ynpsiuqx?], [H]elp: Y
Keep libfaketime? [Ynpsiuqx?], [H]elp: N
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  faketime* libfaketime*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 127 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```